# Eclipse autocomplete not working when using .class package

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete

I've generated .class files from a web service. Now I want to use them in a project that I have. For that I included the .class in a package.

The problem is that Eclipse simply doesn't autocomplete when I try to call the methods wihtin the .class files...in fact for what I could understand it didn't even seem to recognize the package had something in it.

If I use the .java files everything works fine but I'd prefer to use the already compiled and smaller .class files.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify on the term *package*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAR the classes up, then add a build path reference to it for the project in question. You will want to make sure that the classes you compiled actually belong in the package you placed them in, or even this JAR reference method will not work.